# FreeRadius Assign Attributes Randomly For The Sake of Load Balance

Tags: load-balancing, freeradius, radius

We are using `FreeRadius` to authenticate our users to the network and one of the requirements is to load balance DNS across the two DNS servers so when users got their IP after they connect, they receive their DNS servers in random order, for example, some users get 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.2 respectively while other users get them reversed.

To do that, we are assigning random DNS servers attributes to users once they authenticate through the radius. We were thinking of using the FreeRadius rand method along with un lang if statements, however, we thought perhaps there is a better or more elegant way to achieve similar requirements.

The current setup works perfectly (Note that it is not in round-robin style) but it succeeded using un lang along with the rand and expr methods as in the below:

```
if (&User-Name == "bob") {    
        if ("%{expr:%{rand:2}+1}" == "1") { ## A workaround to switch DNS orders 
                update reply {
                        Reply-Message := "Primary DNS comes first"
                        MS-Primary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.1"
                        MS-Secondary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.2"
                        }
                accept
                }
        else {
                update reply {
                        Reply-Message := "Secondary DNS comes first"
                        MS-Primary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.2"
                        MS-Secondary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.1"
                        }
                accept
                }
}
```

Can you advise or suggest a better way to achieve similar results?

**Using**: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.11

Comment: This is a good question! I which more people asked how to do things better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the load-balance keyword

```
load-balance {
    group {
        update reply {
            Reply-Message := "Primary DNS comes first"
            MS-Primary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.1"
            MS-Secondary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.2"
        }
        accept      
    }
    group {
        update reply {
            Reply-Message := "Secondary DNS comes first"
            MS-Primary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.2"
            MS-Secondary-DNS-Server := "192.168.41.1"
        }
        accept      
    }
}
```

You can also swap out the 'group' sections for policy calls or module calls.

IIRC there were some issues using bare update sections in load-balance sections in v3.0.x, so even if you just have the update section you may want to still wrap it in a group.

Comment: Wow, your answer was so quick.

Comment: Sorry to ask more in the comments, just a bit excited and I think it's an extension to this question :)
Are there different load-balancing distribution mechanism within this keyword? And what do you recommend?

Comment: Hm, for 4.0.x https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/4f0ee9c86626769075967ec50ff4cb03bc9b1c2a/src/lib/unlang/load_balance.c#L146 at least I know you can use it in the form `load-balance &Attribute`, where Attribute is an unsigned integer attribute.  Not sure if that's in v3.0.x.

Try it and see? :)

Comment: Didn't understand the &Attribute thing after the load-balance due to lack of the enough knowledge. Never mind, let it go.

I would like to thank you for your initial answer, forgot to tell you that it worked for us and now doing the load balance in production servers!